# iOS app how to only mirror on apple tv and not taking up the whole screen?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I have an iOS app, and when it is mirrored to the Apple TV via Airplay, it actually takes over the entire TV screen, as if UIKit is reading the actual dimensions of the TV. However, this is not what I want - I just want to mirror the app to fit the TV screen (like most other apps) and show black areas instead. How can I do this?

Edit: To clarify, I just want to mirror the screen as it is, and not try to show any additional content.

Edit 2:

The only thing I did in App/SceneDelegate is setting up the delegate class programmatically (because I don't want to set it in the plist):

in my app delegate:

```
  public func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Since we manually create the config instead of reading "DefaultConfiguration" from Info.Plist, we should delete the entry in info.plist.
    let config = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    config.delegateClass = Self.self
    config.sceneClass = UIWindowScene.self
    return config
  }
```

in my scene delegate:

```
  public func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    
    window.rootViewController = rootVC()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
  }
```

And then my plist's "application scene manifest" has the classes setup removed:

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Are you trying to show additional app content on the other screen or are you simply using iOS to mirror your current app as-is? Does your app have any code specific to handling the 2nd screen?

Comment: @HangarRash updated - yep i simply want to mirror the screen and not trying to show anything. I do not have any logic at all.

Comment: The question is, are you mirroring your phone to the AppleTV using the mirroring function in the control center on iPhone or are you connecting a second window using airplay in your app?

Comment: @Paulw11 i am using the mirroring function in control center. As to "connecting a second window using airplay in your app" - I don't know what that is, so probably no

Comment: Then that is strange. When I mirror my phone that way to appletv I get a narrow window with black on either side if the app is in portrait orientation and pretty much fullscreen if the app is in landscape

Comment: @Paulw11 did you use the old app delegate setup or the new "scene delegate" thing?

Comment: I tried a scene delegate app and an app delegate app and a SwiftUI app.  All the same. I don't understand what you are doing, because when you use screen mirroring the app doesn't even know there is an external screen unless you have written specific code to detect it and do something with it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the question to include what I have changed in the app/scene delegate.

Comment: and my app is UIKit, not SwiftUI

Comment: I tried your code and got the same result.  I really don't know how it is possible to get any other result with screen mirroring.  It literally just mirrors what is on the phone screen, so how can the image on the TV be any different to what is shown on the phone screen?  I took photos of my app in both [portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwniB.png) and [landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1TFo.png) orientation

Comment: I believe this is properly done using the mirror screen of the iOS itself, not via app/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue. It's because `willConnectTo` will be called again with `session.role == .windowExternalDisplayNonInteractive` when using airplay. We need to check `session.role`, and early return in that scenario:

```
  public func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    // willConnectTo is called again when connect to an external display (airplay), with a different role type.
    // If we don't do anything, iOS will simply mirror the screen.
    guard session.role == .windowApplication else {
      return
    }
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    
    window.rootViewController = rootVC()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point in your code you are setting up the Window to use for the external display. Here you need to create a window using the size of the device.

You can instantiate the Window with the frame of your main screen like this:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired behavior of mirroring your iOS app to the Apple TV screen with black areas instead of taking up the entire screen, you can follow these steps:

1. Determine the screen resolution of your Apple TV. The default resolution for most Apple TVs is 1920x1080 pixels, which is a 16:9 aspect ratio. However, it's always a good practice to programmatically get the actual screen dimensions to account for variations in different Apple TV models or potential future updates.
2. Modify your iOS app's view hierarchy to match the Apple TV screen's aspect ratio. One approach is to embed your app's content in a container view that maintains the desired aspect ratio (in this case, 16:9). You can add black regions (UIViews with a black background color) around your content view to fill the remaining space.

Here's an example of how to do this programmatically:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Container view to maintain the aspect ratio of the Apple TV screen
    let containerView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set up the container view
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.backgroundColor = .black

        // Add the container view to the main view
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        // Configure constraints to maintain aspect ratio and fill the screen
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        // Add your app's content view to the container view
        let contentView = UIView()
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.backgroundColor = .red // Replace with your actual content view
        containerView.addSubview(contentView)

        // Configure constraints for the content view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor),
            contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 16.0 / 9.0) // Aspect ratio of 16:9
        ])
    }
}
```

By embedding your app's content within the container view, you can ensure that it maintains the desired aspect ratio on the Apple TV screen. The black areas fill in the remaining space, giving your app's content the effect of aspect matching.